# Duplicate site of Stack Overflow

Tags: support

I just came across [stackoverflow.hex1.ru](https://stackoverflow.hex1.ru/questions/35903277/improvement-for-phpstorm-documentation). Is it the original site or just a duplicate of this site? The content on this site are exactly similar to this site.

Is it secure to view [that site](https://stackoverflow.hex1.ru/)?

Comment: Looks like it's **not** secure: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318759/what-is-this-ad-about#318760