# What is this ad about?

Tags: discussion, spam, advertising, phishing

I'm seeing this ad when logged in as myself.

[image]

I'm not sure what it is, but it sure /looks/ like a "buy-your dissertation/review"-type of scam.

Can we get rid of the spammy ad or urge the advertiser to get more relevant and clear about their services?

---

It looks like there is this malicious Stack Overflow clone serving unsecure content:

- *[phishing site called stackoverflow.hex1.ru?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317257/phishing-site-called-stackoverflow-hex1-ru)*
- *[Duplicate site of Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318697/duplicate-site-of-stack-overflow#comment320460_318697)*

This is not a question about how to deal with clone sites. It's a discussion about the perils of possible phishing/scam sites that look exactly like Stack Overflow. I've [reported the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2QS0.png) with google.

Comment: That doesn't look like something we would serve. Could it be your ISP injecting it in?

Comment: I highly doubt it, I'm on a corporate network here.

Comment: Do you see it over https?

Comment: I've never seen anything remotely like that on any SE site. Perhaps you've installed a browser plugin or other adware-driven package recently? Perhaps inspecting the underlying source code gives some more pointers to the origin of this ad.

Comment: Oded: Dunno. Will check. Meanwhile: @Oldskool added [DOM inspection](http://i.imgur.com/ixrN4YR.png) and [cookies served](http://i.imgur.com/PGWD1Vg.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do about a clone service scraping SO sites for content?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253906/what-to-do-about-a-clone-service-scraping-so-sites-for-content)

Comment: @AndrewMedico Not sure this is strictly a duplicate since the OP didn't realise what the site was when posting the question.

Comment: Yup. I think it's more about potential phishing/scams

Comment: You must have been really tired to navigate to the wrong site ;) Hopefully you didn't also log into yourbank.phish.ru also.

Comment: @TravisJ Not at all. I just didn't notice the [full domain name](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PS75Y.png). I will not let myself be guilted or shamed here. In fact, I'm going to be proud for noticing right away **AND** acting upon it. That latter part means the problem is now fixed (for the moment) even though the site has provably been causing problems for a while. No need to thank me.

Comment: @sehe - Not really guilting you here, but you do kind of blame Stack Overflow for this ad at first. Further, you note that this scam is on an SO clone which really is the heart of the issue. If you had initially noticed the clone url, it would have been prudent to follow the instructions immaculately detailed out in *[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)*

Comment: @TravisJ I admit I missed the url initially. I have seen at least 5 different posts that linked to dupes about scraper sites today. None of them seemed to include urgent steps. So, I didn't do them. Regardless, I did report at SO and Google and hopefully it will still have an impact. Cheers. (I don't think this is a scraper site. It does look more like a phishing facade/proxy)

Comment: @sehe - Proxy is mentioned there, but regardless the point wasn't to chide. It definitely helps to eliminate these harmful sites. :)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

According to the source code in the screenshot of your comment, you are using http://stackoverflow.hex1.ru/, but that is not the official Russian site. That would be https://ru.stackoverflow.com/.

I *do* see the ad on stackoverflow.hex1.ru, which seems to be a clone site. Please use the original one. Also, you say you see this ad when logged in. If you logged in on that hex1.ru site, consider your login compromised and change your password immediately.

Comment: Wow. I wonder whether some ad/plugin maliciously redirected me. I use `stackoverflow.com` exclusively. Good spot, I didn't see it. Quick history check showed nothing from that domain before today. I certainly didn't type it :)

Comment: @sehe: You probably want to block it then, either via plugin/addon or hosts file.

Comment: @Zeta It's already added to my hosts file now :) I use https://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/ anyways

Comment: Also noteworthy: [List of SO clone sites to exclude](https://gist.github.com/foobarrio/0dde8b5c4713594cddf5) /cc @Zeta

Comment: @Oldskool thanks! I figured out how I got the clone site (see my pro forma answer). Thanks for spotting the issue.

Comment: How is the @sehe 's "login compromised" with that? If he logins through Google, for instance, all they got is some mildly sensitive account details (like e-mail) and possibly the ability to do some nondestructive actions (like post messages at Google+). To stop that, he can revoke the permission at the provider's site. Conversely, changing the password won't affect this in any manner.

Comment: It might be compromised if i had supplied  any credentials on that site. Which i didn't.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev If it is a phishing site (not sure if it is), of course they would also fake the Google login screen with their own version, capturing email address/password, giving them access to your entire Google account! But good thing OP didn't login on this site :-)

Answer (score 49):

OK, I found how I reached this malicious Stack Overflow clone. It was in my Google results:

[image]

Good thing I noticed something wrong *immediately* (even if not actually the questionable domain name...)

I advise people to block the domain. And:

#### Be careful out there.

Comment: A lesson for us all: We may be smart. We may know a lot about computers. And we may still be fooled.

Comment: If it is in Google results, you should report it to Google so they ban the site for violation of their inclusion policy.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev done: http://i.imgur.com/lFhzCzl.png

Comment: Good thing I have an AdBlocker ;-)

Comment: I see your avatar is emBEARrrassed by your mistake.

Comment: @JanDvorak ad blockers don't usually help against phising/scam sites. (By the way, blocking advertising domains entirely is usually stronger)

Answer (score 20):

The IP address the site is using is now banned, so when visiting you should get the following error:

[image: SO PROXY BANNED]

Comment: Cool. Good to see things working. It might not keep them out for always, but at least it will send a signal that they will have to put in some effort to keep profiting off of other site's popularity.

Comment: This is a very confusing explanation of the error.

Comment: @Xan you are quite welcome to file a report with hex1.ru to make the error message more friendly (hint, don't bother; the longer they don't notice, the better)

Comment: @sehe It's clearly a Cloudflare error

Comment: @Xan Yes? And it it clearly indicates a connection is refused. It's the proxying site that fails to handle this and display a more appropriate message. Turns out the exploiters of that clone aren't very professional about it. Who'd have thought...

Comment: This site has returned: http://stackoverflow.hex1.ru

Comment: @EBrown thanks for reporting this. They are blocked again now.